# ASP.NET shared hosting security and performance for ecommerce aplications

Tags: asp.net, performance, security

Is there any disadvantage on using shared hosting in general (of discountasp.net) for an ecommerce website? security concerns or performance? The site is new and we dont expect many visitors right now, we have at least 30 products.

I am using my own shopping cart, user accounts (Membership provider), credit card processor (paypal), my own CMS, in C# ASP.NET 4.0 webforms and SQL Server 2008.

I dont save credit card information in the database, my system only create an account for users who buy something in the checkout process, and we need only processing power on some paypal apis only in checkout (very low cpu usage I guess).

My website is optimized client-side and server-side, I have the XSS security enabled of ASP and the AntiXSS library of Microsoft in all inputs/outputs (forms, cookies, http headers, query strings and even websevices), stored procedures, parameterized queries to avoid sql injection, SSL connections, anti spam, compiled and obfuscated dlls, encripted web.config, etc...

I am missing something? thanks, and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you a quick answer:

Yes, there are problems. Plenty of them.

Performance is always (typically) worse on shared than on dedicated. Someone might be using all the IO and you get bottlenecked.

Security, as you can't manage the server you have no way of knowing if it's patched, hardeneded etc. If one of the thousand other people on the same shared server manages to exploit it you're done. However, one could argue that if you don't know how to secure a dedicated server it might be better to rely on the shared hosting providers experience.

Also, you have to trust the shared hosting provider not to steal your data etc.

One other thing is that if something crashes you have to wait for the provider to fix it rather then just do it yourserlf. Again, if you don't know how to fix it, it might be better to wait for the provider anyway..

All and all, for your site in the beginning I would go with shared hosting and move up to VPS as soon as you start generating some money on the site.

Comment: At least I don't save credit card info in the database.. don't know anything about VPS D: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: VPS = Virtual Private Server, check www.cloudsigma.com for example. Then you have to trust the VPS provider etc..